# VSCode Debugger: Debugger could not find file .go file

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug my program in VSCode. My Launch.json file looks as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/DS_PA1/srunner/",
            "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}/DS_PA1/srunner/"
        }
    ]
}
```

My folder hierarchy is:

[image: Folder hierarchy]

The debugger is set in the function main():

[image]

On launching, it starts the server and without stopping at the breakpoint it just printed the statement "Started KeyValueServer..."

[image]

Any pointers as to how I can make it stop at func main() so that I can debug manually?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I appear to be seeing the same symptom.